# Multispecies meritocracy: Is it possible?

Tags: society, culture, fantasy-races, interspecies-relations

On Damarian  there are many intelligent species, including many species of half-human half animal. The animals include zebra, camel, donkey, octopus, eel, crab and spider.

Now, according to [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/181683/can-you-have-a-multicultural-meritocracy?rq=1) question, multicultural empires are perfectly sustainable, provided the emperor does not interfere too much. They must maintain order, taxes, and levies, but otherwise is is not a good idea to try and control the various cultures or enforce cultural norms.

Civilization on Damaria is Thousands of years old. Over the millenia various ones has risen and fallen. The first civilisation was ruled by elves; the next by the aquatic species; the next by pterodactyl people, and so forth.

On Damarian, there's a nation called Phoenicia:

- Has existed about 11,000 years, starting with a few dozen Bronze Age cities ruled by Maravneans, and expanded from there.
- Has dynasties, like Earth's China (Counting the modern China, and the [Republic Period](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Republic_of_China_(1912%E2%80%931949)), to be dynasties), that last about 400 Damarian years (877 Earth years) apiece.
- Phoenicia has basically fallen into a rhythm of how its dynasties work: At the start of each one, Phoenicia has a sort of Renaissance, boosting ahead of its neighbors in technology, art, and military power for the first 100 Damarian years (219 Earth years), taking over neighbors with its newfound power boost. The next 200 Damarian years (437 Earth years) are smooth sailing for the Phoenician incarnation of the time, followed by the dynasty's fall for the next 75 Damarian years (165 Earth years) before going into open rebellion for the last 25 Damarian years (55 Earth years) of the dynasty. Then the next dynasty repeats the cycle.
- However, about every 4 dynasties (1,600 Damarian years, or 3,500 Earth years), a "bad apple" dynasty shows up and only lasts 100 years before collapsing into a Dark Ages, when Phoenicia is split into numerous mini-Phoenicias that war with each other. After 200 years, the Dark Ages is ended by a ruler of one of the mini-Phoenicias that takes over the rest in their lifetime, then ushers in a super strong dynasty that lasts 600 Damarian years (1,315 Earth years), with a Golden Age period (The first 100 years of a normal dynasty) that last 200 years, and a normal period of 300 years. This whole cycle lasts 2,500 Damarian years (5,480 Earth years), which means that the current Phoenician dynasty is the newest and the beginning of the third Grand Phoenician Cycle.
- Damarian did not have any sort of gunpowder for almost its entire history, but right out of the gate for the new Phoenician dynasty, someone discovered gunpowder, and immediately made: Fireworks. No one wanted to use gunpowder for anything but fireworks because they were so entrancing (That, and Damarian skipped gunpowder up to this point, making more advanced crossbows, then laser crossbows), so the Damarian equivalent of the UN banned gunpowder for anything but fireworks, but no one wanted to make guns anyway.

Okay, factoids out of sight, we need to focus on Phoenicia's policy. Phoenicia's an empire, after all, and empires are empire because of conquest. This means there are cultures of all sorts under Phoenicia's rule. These are allowed to have their fun, as long as they pay their taxes. However, the many species of Damarian have their own species culture. Avari, when they showed up in Phoenician docks, were mostly used to being able to take out Naven (A natural enemy of theirs), sacrificing them, then eating them. This was quite illegal. Other species have other things and quirks.

***How in the world would any civilization in a world of many species living together remain cohesive, and how would policy work with this fact?***

NOTE: Magic exists in Damarian, but I'd like as little of the answer as possible to consider magic.

Comment: You really need to shorten this up. Long questions by themselves aren't bad, but I have no idea what you're asking even with your thesis statement at the end. What is the actual problem you are having with your worldbuilding that you wish for help with?

Comment: Do you mean you're having trouble understanding how groups of different species with different cultures can live together without trying to exterminate each other or...? If your problem is how to make domination of a colossal empire with several groups with different cultures in a more believable way, taking a better look at the history of Alexander the Great and Genghis Kan, as well as their respective strategies to lessen the impacts of several cultures into maintaining a large empire, might provide some info. It'd be better to be a little more focused on what exactly you need help with.

Comment: @ProjectApex: Bad examples. Both Alexander's and Genghis Khan's empires were ephemeral structures which crumbled into pieces in a very short time. I would say that those are counter-examples of a durable empire... That is, if you want a durable empire, whatever you do don't do what Alexander and Genghis Khan did. (Among other things, do not extend your empire beyond what your communications and transportation technology can support. An empire is supposed to be tied together by economic links; if distant provinces cannot trade, then the empire has no reason to exist.)

Comment: Are you asking about multispecies meritocracy (power is given to people on the basis of their ability) or how to keep a multispecies empire together? Or maybe you want to know whether meritocracy as a political regime can result in/support a stable multispecies empire? Could you clarify (and edit your question to include clarifications)?

Comment: I have tried to slim down the first part of the question. But I have no idea how to slim down the later factoids because I don't know which parts are supposed to be relevant to the question.

Comment: The two most important thing to mention (which you have not) are (1) how different the different species and their cultures are. Presumably they are much more diverse than the different cultures on Earth. (2) What do you mean by meritocracy?

Comment: Your question is opinion based, as your examples are all about the culture, not the species and the qualities of them that would or wouldn't affect cohesiveness. Also, if you kept the first two paragraphs and the last line, eliminating everything else, it would be the same question.

Comment: @AlexP didn't both empires only start to crumble after a mix of disagreements between successors that resulted in the empire weakening after the death of previous leaders that actually managed to properly rule over them? The main reason I included Alexander was due to how he managed to administer several cultures, particularly through the creation of the helenistic culture, but with how you said it I'm wondering if I'm mistaken and ignoring some important factor?

Comment: @ProjectApex: Alexander did not "manage" his empire at all. In fact, Alexander's construction was not really a true empire, it was more in the nature of a personal union of a vast set of completely unrelated countries. Yes, the immediate cause of the crumbling was the unwillingness of the Diadochi to choose an emperor and prolong the charade; but their attitde they was correct -- the large and varied empire had no chance of remaining united. The Mongol Empire fared a little better, lasting for some 50 years, but only because the conquering phase was longer; it never had even one year of peace.

Comment: @ProjectApex: ... The point being that we don't know how the Mongols would have managed their empire, because as soon as they ran out of lands to conquer the empire broke into more manageable pieces.

Comment: @AlexP I see. Thanks a lot for the explanation, I wasn't aware about that.